# The required encoding function doesn't shown in a working code

Tags: swift, cocoa, archive, nscoding

*serialization* and *deserialization* is done by the two method defined in the `NSCoding` protocol as follow

```
encodeWithCoder(_ aCoder: NSCoder) {
    // Serialize your object here
}

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // Deserialize your object here
}
```

In my own `ViewController` (inherited from `UITableViewController`), I have a Array which contain my own object named `Item` and I do implemented the `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` initial function. The `Item` is defined as follow

```
class Item: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var text = ""
    var checked = false

    func toggleChecked() {
            checked = !checked
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.text, forKey: "SLAText")
        aCoder.encode(self.checked, forKey: "SLAChecked")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.text = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "SLAText") as! String
        self.checked = aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: "SLAChecked")
        super.init()
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Instead implement the function `encode(with: NSCoder)` I defined my own serialization function named `saveItems()`

```
 func saveItems() {
        let data = NSMutableData()
        let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: data)

        archiver.encode(items, forKey: "ItemLists") //items is a array of type [Item]
        archiver.finishEncoding()

        data.write(to: dataFilePath(), atomically: true)      
    }
```

**Question**

Why the code is working with out implement the required `NSCoding` function? The code is simplified from a example of the book I'm studying, I didn't find the `encodeWithCoder(_ aCoder: NSCoder)` function at all. Isn't the required means you have to implemented it?

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: How is `Item` defined?

Comment: @appzYourLife I've added the simple version of the `Item` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the code is working with out implement the required NSCoding function?

This is not true.

### NSCoding is a protocol

First of all `NSCoding` is a protocol, not a function. And in order to conform a type to `NSCoding` you need to implement a method and an initializer

```
public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

### Why does your code work?

Let's look at what you are doing

```
archiver.encode(items, forKey: "ItemLists")
```

Here `items` is defined as `[Item]` which is and array of `Item(s)`.
And Array does conform to `NSCoding`. This can be easily tested by writing

```
let nums = [1, 2, 3]

if nums is NSCoding {
    print("Array does conform to NSCoding")
} else {
    print("Array does NOT conform to NSCoding")
}
```

The result is

```
Array does conform to NSCoding
```

### Conclusion

Of course to work properly the element inside of the array must be conform to `NSCodable` too. And since the generic type of your Array is Item (which you made conform to `NSCodable`) the mechanism **does** work properly.

Comment: @appzYourLive  Array does conform to `NSCoding` : this solves my misunderstandings, thanks for your help